# Needing insight to understanding strings in python

Tags: python

Hello I just began coding in high school and was needing help with Strings. I was wanting to write within text files where each text file that is created, would increase in increments of 0.1 for a value say weight going from 0.1 to 1 (lbs) and also have length increase by a factor of 20 from 0 to 80 (inch). But the length will only increase by 20 until 1 lbs has been reached for the previous length.

To further explain, my code that I wrote below will create a txt file. But it will not perform what I would like it to do. I would like it to perform what I'm about to say in the next sentence. Within the first txt file, the file will be weight_0.1_length_0_.txt and in the file would be

```
  "weight of box 0.1"
  "length of box 0"
```

The next txt file would be weight_0.2_length_0_.txt and inside would be

```
  "weight of box 0.2"
  "length of box 0"
```

and so on, But once the weight reaches 1, I would like the length to increase to 20. So the beginning txt file for the value 20 would weight_0.1_length_20_.txt and within the txt file would be

```
  "weight of box 0.1"
  "length of box 20"
```

and this process would be followed until you reach a length of 80. I would have in turn a total of 50 txt files.

below is the code I wrote but only increase the weight of the box by 0.1. If anyone could help I would deeply appreciate it.

```
  Weight = 0.1
  length = 0

  for i in range (10):
      input = 'weight_' + str(Weight) + '_length_' +str(length)+ '_'
      file = open(input + '.txt','w')

      file.write('weight of box ' +str(weight)+ '\n')
      file.write('length of box ' +str(length)+ '\n')
      file.close()

      Weight +=0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing the outer loop for the length.

```
length = 0

for j in range (5):
    Weight = 0.1
    for i in range (10):
        input = 'weight_%.1f_length_%d_' % (Weight ,length)
        file = open(input + '.txt','w')

        file.write('weight of box %.1f\n' % Weight)
        file.write('length of box %.1f\n' % length)
        file.close()

        Weight +=0.1
    length += 20
```

Comment: This code works perfect, Thank you so much! But I had an additional question. Would you still use the outer loops if say our length increments went from 0, 20, 40, 80,160, 250, and 300?

Comment: Instead of looping `for j in range(5)`, you could do this: You could make a list of lengths `lengths= [0, 20, 40, 80, 160, 250, 300]` and then loop over it: `for l in lengths:`. Then, inside the loop, you would assign `length = l` instead of incrementing by 20.

Comment: Whenever I do this, I get txt files that have  weight of box 0.1
length of box [0, 20, 40, 80, 160, 250, 300]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `is_integer` method of decimals, which checks if the decimal is a whole number, then whenever that returns true, add 20 to `length`.

Here is working code for this:

```
weight = 0.1
length = 0

while True:
    if length == 80: # check if length is 80, if so, break out of while loop
        break
    if (weight).is_integer():
        length += 20
    input = 'weight_' + str(weight) + '_length_' +str(length)+ '_'
    with open(input + '.txt','w') as file:

        file.write('weight of box ' +str(weight)+ '\n')
        file.write('length of box ' +str(length)+ '\n')

    weight = round(weight + 0.1, 1)
```

Notice that I am using `round`, to make sure that you don't get rounding errors.

Also, I would recommend using `with open(.. ) as file` instead of `file=open(...)`.  The latter can lead to unforeseen issues, especially if you forget to call `file.close()`.

Lastly, I don't see the utility of creating files in this manner.  If you are doing this solely as a learning experience, you would be better off using `print` statements to check your values:

```
weight = 0.1
length = 0

while True:
    if length == 80:
        break
    if (weight).is_integer():
        length += 20
    input = 'weight_' + str(weight) + '_length_' +str(length)+ '_'
    weight = round(weight + 0.1, 1)

    print(input)
    print(weight)
    print(length)
```

Comment: Commend for faster hands and for noticing/fixing _rounding errors_.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
import numpy
Weight = float(0.1)
length = 0

while(length<=80):

    for i in numpy.arange(0.1,1.1,0.1):
        input = 'weight_' + str(i) + '_length_' +str(length)+ '_'
        file = open(input + '.txt','w')
        file.write('weight of box ' +str(Weight)+ '\n')
        file.write('length of box ' +str(length)+ '\n')
        file.close()
    length+=20
```

Answer (score 0):

Using generators:

```
# template for names to be generated
name_template = 'weight_%0.1f_length_%i_.txt'

# generator function tweak with your requirements.
def generate_names(total, max_length=80, initial_weight = 0.1, initial_length = 0, length_incrementor = 20):
  generated = 0
  weights = [round(x * 0.1, 1) for x in range(1, 11)]
  length = initial_length

  while generated < total:
    if length > max_length:
       return
    for weight in weights:
      yield name_template%(weight,length)
      generated += 1

    length += length_incrementor

total = 50

for name in generate_names(total):
  print(name)
```

Output:

```
weight_0.1_length_0_.txt
weight_0.2_length_0_.txt
weight_0.3_length_0_.txt
weight_0.4_length_0_.txt
..........
..........
weight_0.2_length_40_.txt
weight_0.3_length_40_.txt
```

https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
length = 0

for i in range(5):
    weight = 0
    for j in range(10):
        length = i * 20
        weight += 0.1
        input = 'weight_' + str(round(weight, 1)) + '_length_' +str(length)+ '_'

        with open(input + '.txt','w') as file:
            file.write('weight of box ' +str(round(weight, 1))+ '\n')
            file.write('length of box ' +str(length)+ '\n')
```